# Convert special ASCII Character to XML Compatible string in C++

Tags: c++, xml, ascii

Is there an API C++ which I can use to convert special character to XML comptible string?
Example change

```
We're sorry, <your> item is out of stock will not be Δ available  (until next month). ÿ
```

to

```
We're sorry, &#x03C;your&#x03E; item is out of stock will not be &#x03F; available  &#x028;until next month&#x029;. &#x0FF;
```

Let me explain a bit more about my problem. I work on a Legacy server, which pulls out data reports in Flat files. In to older versions of our client Application, everything works fine with these special chars like <, >, ( etc.

We now are developing a new client, but this client accepts a XML string and render the report on a PHP page. So we made changes to allow the system to output a XML file. But when the XML reaches the client, and if the string contains a funny char like < or ) etc, the DOM parser inside the PHP page starts throwing error. What I want to do is while the XML fine is being created, and if some such special chars are I need to display them in the report hence need to escape 
            <  as &#x03C

I API a function InternetCanonicalizeUrl which will change a string for URL encoding. 
I want something similar for XML

Comment: That's called XML-escaping.

Comment: `Δ` is perfectly valid, as long as your file is UTF8.

Comment: I have a C++ server system and the first string is returned to by the system. I need a C++ API that can convert the above to second type.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for formatting the query for me.

Comment: You didn't get it - Slaks gave you a hint to Google for XML-escaping able APIs or code. Knowing what to look for is 50% of success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an arrage of XML encoded ASCII

```
 //ASCII to To XML Encoding char map. 
 //Each index in the array represents a ASCII char, and the corresponding XML          
 //endcoded string.
//AB 2013/08/02
static const char m_arrAsciiMap[256][8] 
= 
{
    "&#x000;",  "&#x001;",  "&#x002;",  "&#x003;",  "&#x004;",  "&#x005;",  "&#x006;",  "&#x007;",  "&#x008;",  "&#x009;",  "&#x00A;",  "&#x00B;",  "&#x00C;",  "&#x00D;",  "&#x00E;",  "&#x00F;",
    "&#x010;",  "&#x011;",  "&#x012;",  "&#x013;",  "&#x014;",  "&#x015;",  "&#x016;",  "&#x017;",  "&#x018;",  "&#x019;",  "&#x01A;",  "&#x01B;",  "&#x01C;",  "&#x01D;",  "&#x01E;",  "&#x01F;",
    "&#x020;",  "&#x021;",  "&#x022;",  "&#x023;",  "&#x024;",  "&#x025;",  "&#x026;",  "&#x027;",  "&#x028;",  "&#x029;",  "&#x02A;",  "&#x02B;",  "&#x02C;",  "&#x02D;",  "&#x02E;",  "&#x02F;",
    "&#x030;",  "&#x031;",  "&#x032;",  "&#x033;",  "&#x034;",  "&#x035;",  "&#x036;",  "&#x037;",  "&#x038;",  "&#x039;",  "&#x03A;",  "&#x03B;",  "&#x03C;",  "&#x03D;",  "&#x03E;",  "&#x03F;",
    "&#x040;",  "&#x041;",  "&#x042;",  "&#x043;",  "&#x044;",  "&#x045;",  "&#x046;",  "&#x047;",  "&#x048;",  "&#x049;",  "&#x04A;",  "&#x04B;",  "&#x04C;",  "&#x04D;",  "&#x04E;",  "&#x04F;",  
    "&#x050;",  "&#x051;",  "&#x052;",  "&#x053;",  "&#x054;",  "&#x055;",  "&#x056;",  "&#x057;",  "&#x058;",  "&#x059;",  "&#x05A;",  "&#x05B;",  "&#x05C;",  "&#x05D;",  "&#x05E;",  "&#x05F;",  
    "&#x060;",  "&#x061;",  "&#x062;",  "&#x063;",  "&#x064;",  "&#x065;",  "&#x066;",  "&#x067;",  "&#x068;",  "&#x069;",  "&#x06A;",  "&#x06B;",  "&#x06C;",  "&#x06D;",  "&#x06E;",  "&#x06F;",
    "&#x070;",  "&#x071;",  "&#x072;",  "&#x073;",  "&#x074;",  "&#x075;",  "&#x076;",  "&#x077;",  "&#x078;",  "&#x079;",  "&#x07A;",  "&#x07B;",  "&#x07C;",  "&#x07D;",  "&#x07E;",  "&#x07F;",  
    "&#x080;",  "&#x081;",  "&#x082;",  "&#x083;",  "&#x084;",  "&#x085;",  "&#x086;",  "&#x087;",  "&#x088;",  "&#x089;",  "&#x08A;",  "&#x08B;",  "&#x08C;",  "&#x08D;",  "&#x08E;",  "&#x08F;",  
    "&#x090;",  "&#x091;",  "&#x092;",  "&#x093;",  "&#x094;",  "&#x095;",  "&#x096;",  "&#x097;",  "&#x098;",  "&#x099;",  "&#x09A;",  "&#x09B;",  "&#x09C;",  "&#x09D;",  "&#x09E;",  "&#x09F;",  
    "&#x0A0;",  "&#x0A1;",  "&#x0A2;",  "&#x0A3;",  "&#x0A4;",  "&#x0A5;",  "&#x0A6;",  "&#x0A7;",  "&#x0A8;",  "&#x0A9;",  "&#x0AA;",  "&#x0AB;",  "&#x0AC;",  "&#x0AD;",  "&#x0AE;",  "&#x0AF;",
    "&#x0B0;",  "&#x0B1;",  "&#x0B2;",  "&#x0B3;",  "&#x0B4;",  "&#x0B5;",  "&#x0B6;",  "&#x0B7;",  "&#x0B8;",  "&#x0B9;",  "&#x0BA;",  "&#x0BB;",  "&#x0BC;",  "&#x0BD;",  "&#x0BE;",  "&#x0BF;",
    "&#x0C0;",  "&#x0C1;",  "&#x0C2;",  "&#x0C3;",  "&#x0C4;",  "&#x0C5;",  "&#x0C6;",  "&#x0C7;",  "&#x0C8;",  "&#x0C9;",  "&#x0CA;",  "&#x0CB;",  "&#x0CC;",  "&#x0CD;",  "&#x0CE;",  "&#x0CF;",  
    "&#x0D0;",  "&#x0D1;",  "&#x0D2;",  "&#x0D3;",  "&#x0D4;",  "&#x0D5;",  "&#x0D6;",  "&#x0D7;",  "&#x0D8;",  "&#x0D9;",  "&#x0DA;",  "&#x0DB;",  "&#x0DC;",  "&#x0DD;",  "&#x0DE;",  "&#x0DF;",  
    "&#x0E0;",  "&#x0E1;",  "&#x0E2;",  "&#x0E3;",  "&#x0E4;",  "&#x0E5;",  "&#x0E6;",  "&#x0E7;",  "&#x0E8;",  "&#x0E9;",  "&#x0EA;",  "&#x0EB;",  "&#x0EC;",  "&#x0ED;",  "&#x0EE;",  "&#x0EF;",
    "&#x0F0;",  "&#x0F1;",  "&#x0F2;",  "&#x0F3;",  "&#x0F4;",  "&#x0F5;",  "&#x0F6;",  "&#x0F7;",  "&#x0F8;",  "&#x0F9;",  "&#x0FA;",  "&#x0FB;",  "&#x0FC;",  "&#x0FD;",  "&#x0FE;",  "&#x0FF;",
};
```

//Function converts, all non XML allowable ASCII chars to 
//XML encoded string

```
void XMLEncodeString(char *pDestBuffer, char *SourceBuffer)
{
    int buffLen = strlen(SourceBuffer);
    int CurrentPointerPos = 0;  
    for(int i = 0; i < buffLen; i++)
    {
        if ((((BYTE)SourceBuffer[i]) >= 32 && ((BYTE)SourceBuffer[i]) <= 37)                        
         || (((BYTE)SourceBuffer[i]) == 39 )
         || (((BYTE)SourceBuffer[i]) >= 42 && ((BYTE)SourceBuffer[i]) <= 59) 
         || (((BYTE)SourceBuffer[i]) >= 64 && ((BYTE)SourceBuffer[i]) <= 122))
        {
//Check if the Chars are allowed, if yes then dont convert to XML encoded string
//Numbers, Alphabets upper and lower case can be ignored, certain special chars 
// can also be ignored
            pDestBuffer[CurrentPointerPos] = SourceBuffer[i];
            CurrentPointerPos++;
        }
        else
        {
//If the char is not allowed in XML string convert it to the XML encoded equivalent. 
//Replace the single char with the XML encoded string e.g < with &#x03C;
            memcpy((pDestBuffer + CurrentPointerPos),  m_arrAsciiMap[(BYTE)SourceBuffer[i]], strlen(m_arrAsciiMap[(BYTE)SourceBuffer[i]]));
            CurrentPointerPos += strlen(m_arrAsciiMap[(BYTE)SourceBuffer[i]]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but how can I convert it back to the original?

Comment: @NikelArteta what is the format your are getting it? is it still in the  &#x000; format?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify your question?

I'm not sure why you want to use any sort of API. API is an interface you build to extract data from a system. In any case, For processing a string like that, you could make use of switch case.

Could go like:

```
switch ( <variable> ) {
case this-value:
  Code to execute if <variable> == this-value
  break;
case that-value:
  Code to execute if <variable> == that-value
  break;
...
default:
  Code to execute if <variable> does not equal the value following any of the cases
  break;
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. I believe that the OP was looking for a library function that would escape HTML special chars, but did not know the proper phrasing for that.

Comment: I see. Although at some point hes going to have to process that stirng in order to "escape" his special characters. So I was thinking a switch case would work.

Comment: @MasterAM : Switch case is not a very neat way to got. Because there are many special characters.

Comment: No matter what you do, you are going to have to handle each case. There is no magic function that will guess which characters should remain and which should go. You might as well use some occam's razor logic and go with the simplest way to do this.

Comment: Since I will have to parse each char, and check if its XML compatible char, a switch-case will not be a good idea. My solution since I am only limited to ASCII chars is given below.